# Dividing polynomials

Tags: polynomials

A polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients leaves the remainder $15$ when divided by $x-3$, and the remainder $2x+1$ when divided by $(x-1)^2 $. Then the reminder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-3)(x-1)^2 $ is

$a)$ $2x^2 -2x+3$

$b)$ $6x-3$

$c)$ $x^2 + 2x$

$d)$ $3x+6$

I have tried using the rule $ f(x) = p(x)q(x) + r(x) $ and then later trying to substitute the zeros of the roots in the same expression. 
That is if we substitute x=3 in the equation written just above we get the result that $ f(3) = 15 $ since the first term tends to zero as 3 is the zero for $p(x)$.

Two , from the following logic I tried checking the options to see whether they satisfy the conditions $f(3) = 15$ and $f(1) = 3$.

Where I am getting stuck is that options 1 , 2 and 3 all of them satisfy the conditions mentioned above.

The correct answer mentioned is $ (a) $.

Comment: @Pieter21 I have tried using the general division rule , that is d = p.q + r .
But that hasn't given me any leads. 
Although on a general I don't have any other leads.

Comment: @imranfat I could not follow your lead on how to approach the question , would you please elaborate ?

Comment: Because we are hitting a brick wall with giving hints, please add to your Question some information about the math background involved for this problem.

Comment: I am led to believe that we need another condition of the form $f(m)=n$ to solve this, otherwise all 3 options seem valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f=p.(x-3)(x-1)^2+r$ and $r=q_1(x-3)+r_1$ and $r=q_2(x-1)^2+r_2$ 
Now $$f=p(x-3)(x-1)^2+r=(x-3)(p(x-1)^2+q_1)+r_1$$ and $$f=p(x-3)(x-1)^2+r=(x-1)^2(p(x-3)+q_2)+r_2$$

Thus we should have $$r_1=15 \quad *$$ and $$r_2=2x+1 \quad **$$
Because the reminder of $f$ by $x-3$ and $(x-1)^2$ respectively should be $15$ and $2x+1$ .

The first three options satisfied first equation, but we see
$2x^2-2x+3=2(x-1)^2+2x+1$
$6x-3=0.(x-1)^2+6x-3$
$x^2+2x=(x-1)^2+4x-1$

So the answer is **a** !

Comment: So how do I go on about it ? 
Now that all the options satisfy these double roots.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava If you allow to choose only one option, so the question is wrong. If question said reminder of $f$ by $(x-m)(x-n)$ when $m\neq n$ then the answer was unique.

Comment: Would you please show me how does the problem go away if we add the condition   $m = n$

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava If $m=n$ like your question: $m=n=1$, then you have only two equation. I edit my answer because $d$ is false.

Comment: So sorry for the previous comment it was obvious.
Now what I couldn't get is the fact 
when we put $x=3$ in the equation we get remainder equal to fifteen so shouldn't second equation be 

$ 9a + 3b + c = 15 $ 

and similarly the first equation when we put x=1 will become 

$ a + b+ c = 0$

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava  Sorry, I made big mistakes! :) First equation should be $3$. because $2.1+1=3$ .

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava Is there any problem remaining?! Indeed, what's the source of this problem?!

Comment: MathematicianByMistake has successfully eliminated option c from a list of potential answers. If you take a look at the discussion in his answer and help us eliminate one more option that will be great.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava How eliminate option c ?!

Comment: Refer to the comments , I don't think that I have got the hang of it perfectly either !. MathematicianByMistake has did some explanation there.

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that r can only be of the forms that you have mentioned. 
All we know about r from the division algorithm is that its degree will be less than 3 , but how did you come to the conclusion that all possible r's will be of one of the two categories mentioned by you. What if r is a kind of quadratic equation that cannot be written in the form $ q*(x-1)^2 + r$

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava I added more details.

Comment: I understand that remainder of f when it is divided by $ (x-3) $ and $ (x-1)^2 $ should be $ 15 $ and $ 2x+ 1 $ respectively. But how does this lead to the fact that when the same function f is divided by $ (x-3)*(x-1)^2 $ we should get remainder which is corresponds to the forms mentioned above.
In other words , how do I prove that given the info I have the remainder that I will get will correspond to either of the forms of remainders when f was being divided separately by the two polynomials.

Comment: To downvoter : Is it possible to explain why my answer is bad?!

Comment: @ 2000 I did not down vote. Oh and I got your reasoning. Nice work.

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava I know that you are not a downvoter! :)  Indeed, as I mentioned in my previous answer, we have no sufficient info to specify the reminder **unique** but by this information we can say that the solution is not $b,c,d$ !